# Why does my car pull to one side after putting on new used tires?

Tags: tires

I just bought new used tires and got them mounted and balanced on rims.  But now the car pulls to one side very noticeably.  Can this be because of the tires?  Do I have a bad tire?

Comment: Are all tyres the same make/model?

Answer (score 1):

When I drove with the passenger side two wheels on gravel and the driver side two wheels on pavement, the car seemed to drive straight.  And when I did it the other way, it pulled a lot to one side.  So I concluded that the front passenger side tire was bad (When it had traction, it was pulling, and when it didn't it didn't).  I took it off and couldn't find anything wrong with it.  Then I swapped it for the one right behind it.  Now the car doesn't pull.  So that one tire was bad some how, but it's OK on the back.

Answer (score 0):

If the tire thrust centerline is towards one edge of the tire, caster causes it to pull towards one side because both tires aren’t putting equal pressure on the tie rods. This can happen from wear or manufacture defects like broken cords.